# Pattern matching in instances of Tofu [LYAH example]

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, instance, typeclass, type-variables

I'm playing with weird Tofu example from LYAH. I've a little bit simplified it by eliminating record fields from Frank constructor, so here is it:

```
class Tofu t where
    tofu :: j a -> t a j

data Frank a m = Frank (m a) deriving (Show)

instance Tofu Frank where
    tofu x = Frank x
```

It's working and rather clear. But now I want to make value of type `a` to be modified by `tofu` function. So I've started with expansion of value of `x` in instance declaration:

```
instance Tofu Frank where
    tofu (m y) = Frank (m y)
```

as a result I'm getting:

```
tofu.hs:13:15: Parse error in pattern: m
```

Ok, next I've tried to do actual pattern matching inside instance declaration:

```
instance Tofu Frank where
    tofu (Just y) = Frank (Just y)
```

as a result I'm getting:

```
tofu.hs:16:15:
    Couldn't match type `j' with `Maybe'
      `j' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for tofu :: j a -> Frank a j at tofu.hs:16:9
    Expected type: j a
      Actual type: Maybe a
    In the pattern: Just y
    In an equation for `tofu': tofu (Just y) = Frank (Just y)
    In the instance declaration for `Tofu Frank'
```

So, question is: how to work with value of type `a` in instance declaration of tofu? Is it possible to make failed examples working without modification of Tofu class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: You can not.

Assume `t` satisfies `Tofu t`. The function type states

```
tofu :: j a -> t a j
```

which actually means

```
tofu :: forall j a. j a -> t a j   -- t is chosen by the class instance
```

So, it's the caller who gets to choose what `j` and `a` are. The caller can pass a `[Int]` or a `Maybe Char` or a `Either String Bool` (here `j ~ Either String` and `a ~ Bool`). Function `tofu` can not assume any specific case, and must do its job only using "general" operations.

> how to work with value of type a in instance declaration of tofu

There might be no `a` value. E.g.

```
data T a = K Int
```

Since we can instantiate tofu as

```
tofu :: T a -> t a T
```

we can call that as in `tofu (K 6 :: T Bool)` even if there's no `Bool` around.

A similar argument holds for

```
data U a = U (a -> Int)
```

Here a `U Bool` contains a function expecting a `Bool`, instead of providing or "containing" it, loosely speaking.